# Set the width and height of a hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I set the width and height of a hidden element by using another hidden element's width and height?

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++){
   $('#hiddenE1'+i).width($('#hiddenE2'+i).width()).height($('#hiddenE2'+i).height());
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, assuming you got the selectors right.

Comment: @Ninjakannon: Thanks. yes, the code will work only if the elements are not hidden. But the code doesn't work when all `$('#hiddenE1'+i)` and `$('#hiddenE2'+i)` are hidden.

Comment: @Ninjakannon is right. Maybe one thing you're tripping over is that it doesn't effect the DOM since they're hidden. Are you using `display: none` to hide them, try `visibility: hidden` instead and you should see the width/height changes

Answer (score 5):

There is no width when `display: none`. One trick would be to set `position: relative; margin-left: -9999px;`. It will not show on the page but preserve the width. Or, use `visibility: hidden`. The only downside is it will not rip it out of the layout but leave a blank spot.

Answer (score 0):

One can create a class with styles to hide the element i.e.

```
.hide {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

In case  you'd also want to revert you can use another class e.g.

```
.unhide {
   position: initial;
   top: initial;
   left: initial;
}
```

**initial is for the default value, otherwise one could use known values** [read about initial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp)

There are however other ways to hide elements as mentioned [on this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/five-ways-to-hide-elements-in-css/)

In case the link doesn't work:

1.

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

2.

```
.hide {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

3.

```
.hide {
   display: none;
}
```

4.

```
.hide {
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px,0px 0px,0px 0px,0px 0px);
}
```